# Getting the tallest height of every fourth list item

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items that's being generated by a database, the list items fit **four** to a row, without having them in an element being used as a "**row**". So esentially, it's just a plain generated list that happens to fit four to a row before an automatic line break is made due to the container width.

ANYHOW.

I want to get the height of the **tallest** element in each "row" and assign it to the four list elements IN that row.

Example:
If I have -

```
<li height='120'/> 
<li height='140'/> 
<li height='180'/> 
<li height='130'/>
```

I want all of those four to have the height of 180, then my next four list elements have the heights 200, 300, 250 and 280 respectively, I want THOSE four to have a have of 300.

I have some code already, I'm not sure if I'm going about this the proper way, but any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.... Here's what I have thus far..

jQuery:

```
function setListHeight()
{
    var maxHeight = 0,
    halfHeight = 0,
    list = $(".list");

    for( var i = 0 ; i <= $(".list").size() ; i ++ )
    {
        if( i % 4 == 0 )
        {
            $(".list").each(function()
            {
                maxHeight = Math.max($(this).height(), maxHeight);
            });
        }
    }
    list.css({ height : maxHeight });
}

setListHeight();
```

HTML/PHP:

```
foreach( $cats as $cat ) 
{
    echo "<li class='list cf'>";
    echo "<h3 id='".$cat['cat_slug']."'>" . $cat['cat_name'] . "<!--<span class='drop_arrow'>></span>--></h3>";
    $subCategories = $this -> categories -> getSubcatsFromParent( $cat[ 'cat_id' ] );

    foreach($subCategories as $sub)
    {
        if( preg_match('/\s/',$sub['cat_name']) )
        {
            $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $sub['cat_name']));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $name = $sub['cat_name'];
        }
        echo "<a href='category/".$name."'>" . $sub['cat_name'] . "</a>";
    }

    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: what does your html look like? is it a series of unordered lists with 4 list items each?

Comment: Why do you have the inline style 'height' with an <li> element. it doesn't work. are you trying to set the css height?

Comment: It's a unordered list with about 30 items total, I want to grab the largest height of every fourth item and set that as the max height and apply it to that set of list items. ( I would assume it would involve looping through each item, checking to see if that items height is larger than the previous one and setting that as the largest height if it is, then resetting it after every fourth element... Though I can't figure out how to do so )

Comment: @Sammy - It was an example, that's not my actual HTML. I was simply using that to get my point across, I will amend my original post.

Comment: in your php code, group every 4th (or however many) one in a <ul> and then you can use the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(4n + 1)` to select one `<li>` for every 4.

And then use `$(this).nextAll().slice(0,3)` to select the next 3 `<li>` of each one `<li>` selected with `nth-child()`.

Then use `.add()` to select that `<li>` and its 3 siblings at once and apply the `.each()` function to both.

The result is:

```
$('li:nth-child(4n + 1)').each(function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(this).add($(this).nextAll().slice(0,3)).each(function(){
        maxHeight = Math.max($(this).height(), maxHeight);
    }).height(maxHeight);
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Jj8y/3/

Comment: Thank you very much LGVentura. This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought I was fairly jQuery savvy, but apparently I have a long way to go as I've never had a need to use add, nextAll or slice...

Comment: @DrewRobertson93 I also want thank you for this great question. It was a great challenge.. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot use 'height' with a list-item so assuming you're just trying to grab the tallest `<li>` out of the group of 4 this is how you would do it with jQuery.

Let's assume this is your markup:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>text<br/><br/>text</li>
    <li>text<br/><br/>text<br/>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aa<br/><br/><br/>aaaa</li>
    <li>a</li>
</ul>

// write a separate function to get height for current element
function thisHeight(){
    return $(this).height();
}

// loop through the elements and get tallest
$("ul.list").each(function(){
     var maxH = Math.max.apply(Math, $(this).find("li").map(thisHeight));
     $(this).find('li').height(maxH);
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6xxs/)

Comment: I amended my original post with how the php displays my list items.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Sammy, it wasn't quite what I was looking for in this situation but it did help me learn some new ways to go about tackling problems of this nature!

Comment: "First of all you cannot use 'height' with a list-item". This information is not true. You should rethink this.

Comment: <li height='120'/> doesn't do anything.